# Function executes well without error but not returning expected response

Tags: java, function, return

```
public static ArrayList<String> cleanUpUrls(ArrayList<String> oldList,String url) {
    ArrayList<String> cleanedList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i =0; i <oldList.size(); i++) {
        boolean isAnchorLink = false;
        String link = oldList.get(i);
        link = link.toLowerCase();

        //clean href="" part
        link = link.substring(link.indexOf("\"") + 1);
        link = link.substring(0, link.indexOf("\""));

        //check if anchor link
        if (link.charAt(0) == '#') {
            isAnchorLink = true;
        }

        //relative to absolute  
        if (link.charAt(0) == '/') {
            link = url.concat(link);
        }

        //if no http or https then add
        if (link.indexOf("http") == -1 && link.indexOf("https") == -1) {
            String http = "http://";
            link = http.concat(link);
        }

        //remove query strings
        if (link.indexOf("?") != -1) {
            link = link.substring(0,link.indexOf("?"));
        }


        if (!isAnchorLink){

            cleanedList.add(link);
    }

}       System.out.println("xxxx");
        return cleanedList;
}
```

Here is a function **cleanUpUrls** which takes an arrayList of strings as parameter and removes all anchor links i.e. **href =""** part and converts them to absolute links, if they are relative.

The problem is that when I call it, it executes without compile-time/runtime error but does not return expected response. In fact if I print anything after the function call It does not print anything, even the **println("xxx");** does not get display. I am not getting any compilation/run-time errors.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: Paste your main method.

Comment: Iv tried to pinpoint the error by printing things. I dont  use an IDE so dont have access to a debugger.

Comment: You swallow the excptions ... e.printStackTrace(); in catch block please

Comment: added the main method.

Comment: You probably has an exception here:  link = link.substring(0,  link.indexOf("\"")); And since you catch the exception but print nothing it will look like it runs ok

Comment: yes he is, there is a try block around the method call and the catch block is empty. substring will throw an exception in his case since "x" does not contain '\' and its endIndex will be -1

Comment: An empty `catch` block is basically telling the code, "if something goes wrong I don't want to know about it."  And now you're asking why something went wrong that you don't know about...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an exception here:

```
link = link.substring(0, link.indexOf("\""));
```

since in your example `"x"` does not contain `'\'` the second arg will be -1 and will cause `substring` to throw and exception (`IndexOutOfBoundsException`).

Since you catch the exception but print nothing, it will look like it runs with no error so put a print code for displaying the exception:

```
catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Exception caught: " + e);
}
```